# Can you use the "this." keyword to reference an array?

Tags: java, constructor, this

For example:

If you are writing a class constructor and decide that you want to pass an array, could you make use of the "this keyword to reference that array?

```
private int[] a;
private int size;   

public Play(int[] a, int size)
{
this.a = a;
this.size = size;
}
```

My initial guess is no, because it would act similar to c++ where you can't just clone data into an array. Please help me understand it.

Comment: Why not just try this and see if it works?

Comment: An array variable is (in C terms) a pointer to an array. So saying `this.a = a` is assigning `this.a` to point to that same array. No copying is done.

Comment: I did tried it, but like mentioned in the answers and comments, it won't do anything. I, however, now do understand how it works.

Comment: Unlike C, in Java an array is a full-fledged object, and its references can be assigned like any other object.  But, as with other objects, one must understand that it's the *references* (pointers) that are being assigned, not the array itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value
>   that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was
>   invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.
>
> The type of this is the class C within which the keyword this occurs.

So when you use `this` in your constructor, it is a reference to the `Play` object you are constructing. When you do `this.someMember`, you are dereferencing the reference stored in `this` to access the member `someMember` on the object. It doesn't matter that that member is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use this when another variable within the current scope shares the same name and you want to reference to the instance. Theres no difference between a and this.a

Comment: Actually, in the constructor there would be a difference. a would refer to the value that was passed in, while this.a would refer to the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this.a`, it refers to the instance variable `a`. As in the same scope there are two `a`'s now, `this.a` will refer to the instance variable and `a` would refer to the local variable that was passed as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. One reference variable will be assigned a value of another reference variable. Object that they point to does not change and no new objects are constructed.

So it will not `clone` anything.